# VB6-- Full File Selection in Webbrowser

Tags: php, vb6, browser

How can I fill in a FileSelection in a PHP Form through a Visual Basic 6 Webbrowser control?
I want to send a file to upload on a site and I must change File in the page as manualy,
is there any way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple sample project which seems to do what you want.

```vb
'1 form with :
'    1 webbrowser control : name=WebBrowser1
'    1 command button : name=Command1

Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  WebBrowser1.Navigate "www.dailygammon.com/bg/login"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdHeight As Single
  sngCmdHeight = 315
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight - sngCmdHeight
  WebBrowser1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Command1.Move 0, sngHeight, sngWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
  Dim strName As String
  Dim retVal
  strName = "your name"
  retVal = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("login")
  retVal.Value = strName
End Sub
```

I never played with this before, so there are probably quite some things that could be improved. For example, the variable type of `retVal` which is `Variant` now.

Comment: That sample doesn't show how to set the path for a file to upload.